# Symmetric joint PDF

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

I'm reading and solving some problems from the book "Introduction to Probability
Book by Dimitri Bertsekas and John Tsitsiklis".

In the section of the problem on joint PDF, often time they write in the solution: "Use the symmetry of the problem to do... etc".

But I don't see them specifying what symmetry is anywhere.

Could anyone explain:

1. What is symmetry? How do you check if it's present in a problem using joint PDF?
2. What property does symmetry grant?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm assuming the property is that $X$ has the same distribution of $-X$. In particular, $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$.

Comment: For example if you have a joint density which is exchangeable so $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ then you can say $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]$ and $\mathbb P(X<Y) = \mathbb P(X>Y)$ and if this is a continuous distribution then those probabilities are $\frac12$

Comment: They actually say that: $E[X]=E[Y]$. But I've seen a problem stating that $E[X]=0$, again because of symmetry. Might it be it has to with axe are they symmetric?

Comment: If the pdf of $X$ is symmetric about the origin, then $E(X)=0$  Look at the normal distribution.

Comment: Yeah, that I get. I don't understand what is it means to have symmetry in $f(x,y)$. How do you check and what it gives